# (Hive) SQL retrieving data from a column that has 1 to N relationship in another column

Tags: sql, hive

How can I retrieve rows where BID comes up multiple times in AID

You can see the sample below,  AID and BID columns are under the PrimaryID, and BIDs are under AID. I want to come up with an output that only takes records where BIDs had 1 to many relationship with records on AIDs column. Example output below.

[image]

I provided a small sample of data, I am trying to retrieve 20+ columns and joining 4 tables. I have unqiue PrimaryIDs and under those I have multiple unique AIDs, however under these AIDs I can have multiple non-unqiue BIDs that can repeatedly come up under different AIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Hive supports window functions. A window function can associate every row in a group with an attribute of the group. Count() being one of the supported functions. In your case you can use that a and select rows for which that count > 1
The partition by clause you specify which columns define the group, tge same way that you would in the more familiar group by clause.

Something like this:

```
select * from 
  (
    Select *, 
    count(*) over (partition by primaryID,AID) counts 
    from mytable
   ) x
   Where counts>1
```